# Why am I getting "Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component"?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm making an app with React Native and am getting
this error:

> Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.

Code:

```
  const [childsName, setChildsName] = useState('');
  const [childsNameToBeLinked, setChildsNameToBeLinked] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [code, setCode] = useState('');
  const [isParent, setParent] = useState(false);
  const [isChild, setChild] = useState(false);
  const [isLinked, setLinked] = useState(false);
  const [allDoneForParents, setAllDoneForParents] = useState(false);
  const [childsNameAddedNotif, setChildsNameAddedNotif] = useState('');
  const [uri, setUri] = useState('');

  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {!isParent && !isChild && (
          <View>
            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
               <Button title="This Is Child's Phone" onPress={() => setChild(true)} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
              <Button title="This Is Parent's Phone" onPress={() => setParent(true)}  />
            </View>

          </View>
        )}
        {isParent && (
          <View>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
              <TextInput placeholder='@' onChangeText={(val) => setEmail(val)} value={email} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
              <TextInput placeholder='Enter Code' onChangeText={(val) => setCode(val)} value={code} />
            </View>
            {childsNameAddedNotif && (
              <View>
                <Text>{childsNameAddedNotif}'s Phone Has Been Linked</Text>
              </View>
            )}
            {!childsNameAddedNotif && (
              <View style={styles.submitBtn}>
                <Button title='Submit' onPress={handleSubmit} />
              </View>
            )}

            <View style={styles.backBtnContainer}>
              <BackBtn onPress={() => setParent(false)} />
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
        {isChild && !isLinked && !code && (

              <View>
                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                  <TextInput placeholder="Child's First Name" onChangeText={(val) => setChildsName(val)} value={childsName} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.submitBtn}>
                  <Button title='Submit' onPress={handleSubmit} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.backBtnContainer}>
                  <BackBtn onPress={() => setChild(false)} />
                </View>
              </View>
          )}
        {isChild && !isLinked && code && (
              <View>
                <Text>OK, now use your phone, tap on This Phone Parent's Phone, enter your email and {code}</Text>
              </View>
          )}
        {isLinked && !allDoneForParents && (
          <View>
            <View>
              <Text>{childsNameToBeLinked}'s Phone Is Now Linked</Text>
              <Text>Would You Like To Link More Children ?</Text>
            </View>
            <View>
              <Button title='Yes' onPress={() => setLinked(false)} />
            </View>
            <View>
              <Button title='No' onPress={() => setAllDoneForParents(true)} />
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
        {allDoneForParents && (
          <View>
            <Text>All Done For You Now. Little Angel Will Notify You If Needed.</Text>
            <Text>Have a Nice Day :) </Text>
          </View>
        )}

      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>

  );
}
```

Can you see where my strings aren't within the Text component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this happens to me quite often and it's usually, imo, the text editor. I copied your code and didn't get this error. I also can't see where there is an inappropriate string outside of a Text component. Since I couldn't, here are a few different ways you can troubleshoot without having to send us all your code.

The quickest way I solve this is to comment out everything and slowly uncomment each section until I find where the error is coming from and go from there. Usually it's a space your can't see or improper conditional.

If you're using [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), sometimes if there is a space after a tag (example: <View>) when you press ctrl + s to save, it will take that space as a text string. Usually, however, it leaves {" "}.

If none of that works, you can try to convert your string conditionals to

```
childsNameAddedNotif !== ""
```

While it means the same thing, it's worth a try because sometimes this is my problem.

Adding the template strings to your Text component would make no difference the way you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue coming from this line

```
 <Text>{childsNameToBeLinked}'s Phone Is Now Linked</Text>
```

You need to add the template string and dollar sign for the variable.

```
<Text>{`${childsNameToBeLinked}'s Phone Is Now Linked`}</Text>
```

The same for

```
<Text>{childsNameAddedNotif}'s Phone Has Been Linked</Text>
```

It should be

```
<Text>{`${childsNameAddedNotif}'s Phone Has Been Linked`}</Text>
```

Comment: It made no difference.

Comment: @Mark, you still have another issue, I just update the answer.

Comment: I've edited it in both instances. I figured you meant both instances.